# Will PHP Autoloader load when calling the "::class" constant?

Tags: php

PHP has a special feature called class constant `::class` that returns the name of that class.

For example `FooClass::class` just returns the string `"FooClass"`.

**Question**: when using `::class`, is that class *auto-loaded*? I think no. But any source?

Context:

I'm 99% sure that there is not a case where the class is auto-loaded (at least in PHP 8.2), but I'm unsure whenever I should rely on this "not being auto-loaded" as a stable feature. And I would like to rely on this, since my root problem is having a giant legacy application with a lot of methods returning some classes, like `string getEditorClassName()` and all of them are returning class names as simple hardcoded strings like `return "FooEditor";`. This is not really-well integrated into IDEs so we would like to refactor and adopt `return FooEditor::class;` but I have the concern that the class could be auto-loaded in some unclear corner cases or future cases, differently than before with hardcoded strings, and this may cause performance penality with class lookups without actual instantiation.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

According to the official documentation, the `::class` is resolved at compile time. But it does not clarify whenever it could trigger `spl_autoload_register()` in some cases. Anyway, the feature works also if the class was never compiled. And, doing some tests, it seems to never load. Also, I'm quite sure that the `::class` always returns a string and does not cause an error if the class is not existing, but I'm not quite sure if it can try (or will try) to auto-load it, and then just silently return a string.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

So, again:

According to your answer, would you suggest to rely on this behavior (e.g. not being auto-loaded)? Thanks!

Feel free to share the PHP source code, or commit as reference. If it can help, I know the feature was released in PHP 5.5.

https://www.php.net/releases/5_5_0.php

---

Unrelated questions:

- [Will PHP Autoloader load when calling a class constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28502523/will-php-autoloader-load-when-calling-a-class-constant) - this is about loading a class constant, not the `::class` constant.

Comment: If you would like extra context, this question is linked from this code review: https://we.phorge.it/D25524

Comment: In my experience, I was able to just run the code in a debugger, btw. It did allow me to debug into the autoloader.

Comment: Another note: https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdoc-types#class-string. Adding that might make your IDE more cooperative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can 100% rely on the fact that the class will not be auto-loaded when using `ClassName::class`. Here it's clearly explained as a stable feature:

https://www.php.net/oop5.basic#language.oop5.basic.class.class

> The class name resolution using ::class is a compile time transformation. That means at the time the class name string is created no autoloading has happened yet. As a consequence, class names are expanded even if the class does not exist. No error is issued in that case.

P.S.

I was not able to find that page from the internal PHP search engine, but only by serendipity. Maybe if somebody has some time to edit the PHP documentation, that page could maybe be linked from this page at least, to make it less orphan:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php